# VBA write csv file instead writes a xcsv file

Tags: excel, vba, csv

Im pretty new to this so I doubt I will be able to provide any answers to any questions but I can summarize my hopeful outcome.

I have an excel sheet that I need to convert to a CSV file. This would happen over multiple times throughout my project's timeline so I am attempting to create a VBA code with a button to write the csv file.

My goal is to have the code overwrite an existing CSV file that is located within the same excel file file's path

So far, this is what I have:

Sub write_csv_xls()

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

xls = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
Length = Len(xls) - 3
csv = Left(xls, Length) & "csv"
dlist = Left(xls, Length - 1)

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    csv, FileFormat:=xlCSV, _
    CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    xls, FileFormat:=xlNormal, _
     Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:= _
    False, CreateBackup:=False
    
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

ActiveSheet.Name = "TITLEBLOCK_DRAWING LIST"
ActiveCell.Select

MsgBox "CSV and XLS files saved"
```

End Sub

This is creating an xcsv file in the correct file path and it is giving me the correct output that I can read in a text file. For my application, the code does need to work for a csv file. Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your Excel file name is probably something like "workbook.xlsm", and in your code you are only losing the right 3 characters. Far better (to deal with old .xls files as well as .xlsm files) is to use `InStrRev` to find the first occurrence of the "." from the right:

```
csv = Left(xls, InStrRev(xls, ".")) & "csv"
```

Regards,